# Achieving translucency of 3D object in Metro Application

Tags: windows-8, 3d, windows-store-apps, direct3d11, translucency

I am working on a 3D project for Windows Store (Metro Application) and using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8 and Blender for creating 3D objects. I am importing an fbx mesh file of a 3D object (using Visual Studio Starter Kit) and I want some part of that object to be translucent (50% opacity). I have tried 3 png textures with Lambert shader on the 3D object and the following are the results which I am getting:

1) Opacity:100% 
   Object Appearance: Opaque

2) Opacity: 0%
   Object Appearance: Transparent

3) Opacity:50%
   Object Appearance: Opaque (same as 100%)

I want to achieve translucency but even after using 50% opacity of texture, I am not able to get what I want. Please suggest me some solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Starter Kit is mostly just a simplified demo of the VS exporter. It doesn't support blend states, so changing the material setting isn't going to do anything.

You may have more luck making use of [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929)'s Model support for CMO, which has more control over alpha blending usage.